# Moving / Copying ¨All mail¨ label messages to INBOX label

Tags: thunderbird, gmail, imap, transfer, inbox

in order to close a GMail account from Google Workspace (of mine) I need to get a copy of ¨All email¨ label messages to the INBOX label so I can move them easily to another GMail account with extra space bought with Outlook 2021.

After trying multiple ways (Outlook 2021 doesnt show ¨All mail¨ folder into the hierarchy, GMail webmail, old and new view is unable to move / copy those messages to INBOX, Mozilla Thunderbird latest daily release x64 shows the ´All mail¨ folder but once I select the 13,X GB messages asking the client to move or copy them to Inbox it stalls).

According to the Google Workspace support just an API or something external to Google can do that job, so Im here to asking a little help from you.
I really need to close that account coz starting September Google will let me pay for it and its now useless.

IF POP3 protocol could have access to ´All mail¨ label / folder I will download all those messages on my email client (local copy) in order to reupload them, but we all know that POP3 protocol only can download Inbox messages, and that Exchange server (I.E.) isnt available even for Google Workspace GMail accounts.

With IMAP protocol I suppose to have tried everything but not buying the Missive email client (if i dont wanna pay for an extra GMail account and already am using two email clients why buying a third one?).

Hoping to get some news from you really soonest, Im quite desperate.

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Do it piecemail (oops, piecemeal) from Thunderbird:

1. Select 100 or so messages *All Mail*
2. Copy that batch directly to another account through T'bird, or copy them to a local folder.
3. In T'bird, delete that batch.
4. Go to Step 1. until finshed.

You can experiment to see if moving *more* than 100 at a time works faster, but either way, it should not take too long to complete this repetitive task. Two reasons to do so manually, rather *via* a looping script, are to see if there are errors and to wait until one batch completes before starting the next.